# Solve this Google Blockly maze

Tags: blockly

I'd appreciate some help finishing this blockly maze.

https://blockly-games.appspot.com/maze?lang=en&level=10&skin=0

[image]

This how far I was able to get.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether it is optimal solution, but it works:

[image]

```
while (notDone()) {
  moveForward();
  if (isPathLeft()) {
    if (isPathForward()) {
      if (isPathRight()) {
        turnRight();
      } else {
        turnLeft();
      }
    } else {
      turnLeft();
    }
  } else {
    if (isPathRight()) {
      turnRight();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is mine. Thanks to an interview that includes a segment to assess my capability.

[image]

Congratulations!
You solved this level with 16 lines of JavaScript:

```
while (notDone()) {
  if (isPathRight()) {
    turnRight();
    moveForward();
  } else {
    if (isPathLeft()) {
      turnLeft();
      moveForward();
    }
  }
  if (isPathForward()) {
    moveForward();
  } else {
    turnRight();
  }
}
```

The milestone comes at the last junction where you still have to turn right when your goal is to head left. So have a code to take care of the event when there is no path forward. Let it turn left or right. no matter since your previous path left or path right will do the turning and motion accordingly.

meaning, can be: if (isPathForward()) { moveForward(); } else { turnRight(); } }

or if (isPathForward()) { moveForward(); } else { turnLeft(); } }